# Error with GROUP_CONCAT in Elequent request

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to make request to database with eloquent (Laravel 4.2) .. i have a problem with `GROUP_CONCAT` SQL function :

```
$articles = Article::join('tags', function ($join) {
            $join->on('articles.id', '=', 'tags.article_id');
        })->get(array('articles.*', 'GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_id SEPARATOR ', ') as tags'));
```

i got this sql error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_id SEPARATOR ' in 'field list' (SQL: select `articles`.*, `GROUP_CONCAT(tags`.`tag_id SEPARATOR `, `)` as `tags` from `articles` inner join `tags` on `articles`.`id` = `tags`.`article_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions):

```php
$articles = DB::table('articles')
                ->select(DB::raw('articles.*', 'GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_id SEPARATOR ', ') as tags'))
                ->join('tags', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('articles.id', '=', 'tags.article_id');
                })->get();
```

Comment: it doesn't works :( it doesn't return tags in the results